# imagefill() causing 'Premature end of script headers'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm posting because after hours of searching I'm utterly confounded. Here's the deal. My Laravel application uses the PHP Image Workshop bundle. Everything seems to be working fine, except if I try to make a `resizeInPixel()` call or a `cropInPixel()` call (or similar calls) the server throws an internal server error. If I investigate the error log I see:

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

This *only* occurs when I use the resize and crop related methods (i.e. image processing). I can `initFromPath()` with no issue, and I can use the `save()` method without issue. Only the image processing methods cause the internal server error.

I've also read online that this can be the result of a `suphp_log` file exceeding 2GB. I've tracked down and cleaned out that file, but to no avail.

Any thoughts are most welcome! Even if they're just general "have you tried...".

***UPDATE***

I've narrowed it down to a particular line in the Image Workshop code. This line is causing the error:

```
 imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);
```

Additionally, this error only occurs when the color is created using `imagecolorallocatealpha`, NOT when it is created using only `imagecolorallocate`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great hints for solving this issue at [Liquidweb.com](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-error-premature-end-of-script-headers/). My money is on #2 (see bold text) because you are getting the error when doing image manipulations:

> Sometimes when executing a script you will see an error similar to the following:
>
> `Premature end of script headers: /home/directory/public_html/index.php`
>
> This error occurs because the server is expecting a complete set of HTTP headers (one or more followed by a blank line), and it doesn’t get them. This can be caused by several things:
>
> 1. Upgrading or downgrading to a different version of PHP can leave residual options in the httpd.conf. Check the current version of PHP using php -v on the command line and search for any lines mentioning another version in the httpd.conf. If you find them, comment them out, distill the httpd.conf and restart apache.
> 2. **The RLimitCPU and RLimitMEM directives in the httpd.conf may also be responsible for the error if a script was killed due to a resource limit.**
> 3. A configuration problem in suEXEC, mod_perl, or another third party module can often interfere with the execution of scripts and cause the error. If these are the cause, additional information relating to specifics will be found in the apache error_log.
> 4. If suphp’s log reaches 2GB in size or larger you may see the premature end of scripts headers error. See what the log contains and either gzip it or null it. Restart apache and then deal with any issues that the suphp log brought to light. The suphp log is located at: /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log
> 5. The script’s permissions may also cause this error. CGI scripts can only access resources allowed for the User and Group specified in the httpd.conf. In this case, the error may simply be pointing out that an unauthorized user is attempting to access a script.

**UPDATE:**

---

After some more info in the comments, I still feel this is a memory related thing.

According to this SO wiki: [About gdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gdlib/info)

> Warning: Image functions are very memory intensive. Be sure to set memory_limit high enough

What is your PHP **memory_limit**? Can you crank it up a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm not finding RLimitMEM or RLimitCPU in the httpd.conf. Any ideas? As a sidenote, I've tried significantly increasing the memory limit for scripts on the website (via php.ini) and that hasn't impacted the error.

Comment: Is this your own server? Or a shared host? Also, what's happening in in the apache error_log? Any related details there?

Comment: It's dedicated hosting. The apache error log is the one that's displaying the 'Premature end of script headers,' so it doesn't shed much light on the situation unfortunately.

Comment: I still feel this is a memory thing. I've added to my answer.

Comment: I've tried increasing the memory limit up to 512M (default is 16M), but with no change. I've also run phpinfo from the affected code area to verify that the 512M limit is being used, and it does indeed show 512M as the memory limit. I absolutely agree, though, it seems like a memory issue, based on the symptoms.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the image you are manipulating? Could there be a gigantic or malformed image in the works? Also, the issue showing up when using **imagecolorallocatealpha** but not with **imagecolorallocate** makes perfect sense. The former includes an alpha channel which is working with 1/3 more data than the latter.

Comment: I've tried it with a 100x100 image; same error. It's very strange! In any case, the images I'm working with are always JPEG's, so I've just changed the line to `imagecolorallocate`, which works for me.

Comment: Man, that is strange. Sorry I wasn't able to find an answer for you. If you ever do figure it out, please come back and let us know.